# Apply stream to filter out all elements satisfying the condition except one

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class:

```
public class Offer {

    private final OfferType type;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

and enum type:

```
public enum OfferType {
    STANDARD, BONUS;
}
```

My use case is that having a list of offers as an input, I want to filter out all the standard ones except the cheapest one. So for the following input data

```
List<Offer> offers = Arrays.asList(new Offer(OfferType.STANDARD, BigDecimal.valueOf(10.0)),
            new Offer(OfferType.STANDARD, BigDecimal.valueOf(20.0)),
            new Offer(OfferType.STANDARD, BigDecimal.valueOf(30.0)),
            new Offer(OfferType.BONUS, BigDecimal.valueOf(5.0)),
            new Offer(OfferType.BONUS, BigDecimal.valueOf(5.0)));
```

I expect the following result

```
[Offer [type=STANDARD, price=10.0], Offer [type=BONUS, price=5.0], Offer [type=BONUS, price=5.0]]
```

Is there a single-line statement (using streams or any third-party library) that allows for doing that?

Comment: *I want to filter out all the standard ones except the cheapest one.* -- What do you mean by this?

Comment: "standard ones" means "those with value OfferType.STANDARD on the **type** field" and "cheapest one" means "the one with lowest **price** value among standard offers"

Comment: Then how does *type=BONUS* come as part of your expected output?

Comment: @NicholasK, I don't know how you understand my description but my intention is to output all the BONUS offers and only one STANDARD offer with the smallest price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with a single stream operation though:

```
List<Offer> some = offers.stream()
                         .filter(x -> x.getType() != OfferType.STANDARD)
                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

offers.stream()
      .filter(x -> x.getType() == OfferType.STANDARD)
      .min(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice))
      .ifPresent(some::add);
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, may be spin a custom collector:

```
 public static Collector<Offer, ?, List<Offer>> minCollector() {
    class Acc {

        Offer min = null;
        List<Offer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        void add(Offer offer) {
            if (offer.getType() == OfferType.STANDARD) {
                if (min == null) {
                    min = offer;
                } else {
                    min = offer.getPrice()
                               .compareTo(min.getPrice()) > 0 ? min : offer;
                }
            } else {
                result.add(offer);
            }
        }

        Acc combine(Acc another) {
            this.min = reduceMin(this.min, another.min);
            result.addAll(another.result);
            return this;
        }

        List<Offer> finisher() {
            result.add(min);
            return result;
        }

        private Offer reduceMin(Offer left, Offer right) {
            return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(left, right),
                                   Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice)));
        }
    }

    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::combine, Acc::finisher);
}
```

And usage would be:

```
List<Offer> result = offers.stream()
                           .collect(minCollector());
```

Comment: `.min(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice))` was where you beat me in time :)

Comment: @nullpointer .. or a custom collector, but took a while to write it

Comment: Coincidently that's where I relied on the simple for loop approach `List<Offer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        BigDecimal min = BigDecimal.ZERO; for (Offer offer : offers) {
            switch (offer.getType()) {
                case STANDARD:  if (offer.getPrice().compareTo(min) < 0) {
                        min = offer.getPrice();
                    }  break;
                case BONUS:
                default:
                    result.add(offer);
                    break;
            }     }
        result.add(new Offer(OfferType.STANDARD, min));`. similar accumulator.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner my bad explaining - removed the comment, the finisher is run after all the combiners are run, this is when that min will be put into the result

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner oh shoot, indeed!

Comment: Good you noticed that either min could be null! (I had missed it)... A variant could be `BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice))).apply(left, right)`

Comment: I don’t think that your `reduceMin` is a win over the `if` statement you used in the `add` method. You just need to change the `else` to `else if(right != null)` and have a construct that works for both, `add` and `combine` (where `right` is the same as `offer.min`)…

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a single-line statement (using streams or any third-party
>   library) that allows for doing that?

Do things in two times, it would be more readable.

1) Compute the cheapest price for the `Standard` type offers :

```
Optional<Offer> minPriceOffer = 
offers.stream()
      .filter(o -> o.getType() == OfferType.STANDARD)
      .min(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice));
```

2) Exclude `Standard` offers with this price in the collected list :

```
List<Offer> offersFiltered = 
offers.stream()
      .filter(o -> {  
               if (o.getType() == OfferType.STANDARD                         
                    && !o.getPrice().equals(minPriceOffer.get().getPrice())) 
                  return false;
               // else
               return true;
             }
       )
      .collect(toList();
```

Comment: Because we want to exclude the price only for the standard offers (not the other types).

Comment: `.min(Offer::getPrice)` does not work; you need `.min(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice))`. On the other hand, you can simplify your second predicate: `.filter(o -> o.getType() != OfferType.STANDARD || o.getPrice().equals(minPriceOffer.get().getPrice()) )`. You don't need `isPresent()`, as, when you encounter an `OfferType.STANDARD`, the optional can't be empty. In principle, you could also use `filter(o -> o.getType() != OfferType.STANDARD || o == minPriceOffer.get() )`, depending on how duplicate minimum prices ought to be handled.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your inputs. For the second point, I know it but I avoid this way to precisely keep all Offers with the minimal price, it it exists multiple of them.

Comment: Well, that was the 3rd point. The second was `.filter(o -> o.getType() != OfferType.STANDARD || o.getPrice().equals(minPriceOffer.get().getPrice()) )`, which still keeps all elements with the same price as the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two streams that:

1. Group by offer type
2. converts each group's offers to a stream
3. selects the `standard` offers, sorts them, and limits to 1 element (min by price)
4. Merges the two streams

The code looks like this:

```
List<Offer> result = offers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Offer::getType))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getKey() == OfferType.STANDARD ? 
                            entry.getValue().stream()
                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice))
                            .limit(1)
                          :  entry.getValue().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: and `sorted` + `limit(1) `could better be `min`

Comment: @Eugene I suppose that's a comparison with your answer. I'll always choose to run the stream once whenever possible. This solution avoids running two streams on `offers`

Comment: @nullpointer I could well use `min`, but I need a stream because that's an argument for `flatMap`

Comment: @ernest_k got it, overlooked for the sake of `.min(Comparator.comparing(Offer::getPrice)).stream()` (Java9+)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Offer> result = offers.stream().filter(e -> OfferType.BONUS == e.getType()).collect(toList());
offers.stream().filter(e -> OfferType.STANDARD == e.getType()).findAny().ifPresent(result::add);
```